# The class is set as ReadOnlyTransactional but method is readOnly=false with default propagation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-transactions

Calling class:

```
class ABC {
    @Autowired
    private Test test;
}
```

And the service class.

```
@Service
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
class Test {

    @Transactional(readOnly=false)
    public boolean save() {
       //do work
    }
}
```

From weblayer class `ABC` I am calling test.save() through REST API.

1. Here in REST layer when the call is made there is no existing transaction, ideally when save() starts it should start readOnly=FALSE transaction but apparently it is taking the class level transaction definition which is readOnly=TRUE, is it correct ? What's the right behavior? How to solve it?
2. If i make the propagation as REQUIRES_NEW for save() , will it solve my problem?

getting below exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't write to a readonly object
    at org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.internal.strategy.ReadOnlyEhcacheEntityRegionAccessStrategy.update(ReadOnlyEhcacheEntityRegionAccessStrategy.java:115)
    at <...etc...>
```

Comment: getting below exception


    *Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't write to a readonly object at org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.internal.strategy.ReadOnlyEhcacheEntityRegionAccessStrategy.update(ReadOnlyEhcacheEntityRegionAccessStrategy.java:115)
        at org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.int*

Comment: Just to make sure: the `@Transactional` annotation belongs to Spring?

Comment: Yes it below belongs to Spring

Comment: Ok, so how it works by default: annotations are taken from method first, then class. All attributes are queried separately. However, all of that can be overridden by TransactionAttributesParser instance (or something named along these lines). If your environment meddles changed that property, result might be different.

Comment: Since it's been two days and no answers, I suggest you manually debug these parsers on server startup. I think our pet system has something along the lines of what you're showing, and we havent been experiencing your problem. However, we don't use Hibernate, so I'm not fully qualified to answer (so I won't).

Comment: The issue is not related to transaction annotation but the issue is with the caching. As table is master data and its not supposed to be modified and in this method we are modifying the  table. The caching is put on the entity is for readonly table.

Comment: `@Table(name = "table_name") `@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY, region = "enum-cache") `public class <ClassName>`

Comment: So if your entitiy is supposed to be readonly, you shouldn't modify it during runtime. Otherwise you shouldn't have marked it readonly.

Comment: yes @M.Prokhorov that's what is intended